# When "Use AJAX" is set to Yes on a View with Better Exposed Filters, the old search results are not cleared

Tags: forms, ajax

Using Drupal 8, when AJAX is enabled on an exposed filter old search results aren't removed. I don't see any console errors but it seems that 'Use AJAX' isn't clearing the div before loading the next results. Is there a better way to go about fixing this other than attaching behaviors to Drupal AJAX?